# Archiving in xcode takes very long time

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

While archiving my iOS project in xcode 5.0.2 as 'Debug' configuration selected takes hardly couple of minutes, while the same with 'Release' configuration selected takes more than 30 minutes. Process gets stuck at Analysing(shallow) for most of the time. The same is not true for other projects. Have anyone have this issue? Thank you.

Update: While Archiving it gets struck once in the middle of Analyzing and again at the end of the analyzing(shallow).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are running `Product->Archive` and not `Product->Analyse`? The analyzing step you mention is a give away. Another possibility is that you somehow changed your archive step to do an analyze.

**Update**:
Based on your comment: *turn off analyze in your archive step*.

Comment: I am running Product -> Archive. btw how can you change 'your archive step to do an analyze'. Thanks for answering, but I suggest you to use  comments if you don't have complete answer. :)

Comment: That was a complete answer. ;-) Sometimes when people don't give a lot of information in their question, people here ask leading questions to give them the "eureka!" moment on their own. In this case, that's exactly what happened -- you can't have it both ways: you can analyze as needed / adhoc and archive separately, or you can add analyze to archive and pay the toll in build time. My current project is about 55 seconds to build-from-clean in Debug, about 1m15s in Release, and about 2m in Analyze (236 files, ~16k LOC). 'Analyze' is pretty amazing, regardless. :-)

Comment: I agree. Still I couldn't find where I can enable/disable analyse for archiving in xcode 5. Even with analysing enabled, 30 mins difference to Archive between Debug and Release configuration is weird.

Comment: Today its "archiving" 6 hours. (Build, "Run" - about 3-5 sec). Weird.